# Template Debugging for Non-Administrator

Tags: debugging

Is there a way to turn on Template Debugging even if you are not an administrator?

I have lots of pages that need debugging and they can only be accessed by users which are of the member group "Members"?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The template debugger logic requires the Super Administrator member group before its displayed. You'd have to modify EE's core to get this working the way you want.

Comment: If you're up for modifying EE to accommodate this, you need to open up `system/expressionengine/controllers/ee.php` and `system/expressionengine/libraries/Template.php`